# Getting unexpected (not) state update in React for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function, which is executed upon every change of an input form. It changes a state variable (`foo`, `bar`) and executes a function (`_validate()`) which in turn relies on `foo` and `bar` to set another state variable, `valid`.

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(null);
const [bar, setBar] = useState(null);
const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

...

const _validate = () => {
    console.log(foo); // this renders previous value
    console.log(bar); // this renders previous value
    if(foo.length !== 0) {
        setValid(true);
    } else {
        setValid(false);
    }
}

const _onChange = (origin, val) => {
    if(origin === 'sth') {
        setFoo(val);
        _validate();
        if(valid) {
            // do sth
        }
    } else { 
        setBar(val);
        _validate();
        if(valid) {
            // do sth
        }
    }
    ...
}

console.log(foo, bar);  // this renders current value

render() {
    ...
}
```

If I do a `console.log()` in `validate()`, the state variables `foo`and `bar` are not the current ones, which are set after the `_onChange()` is called. They are the old, previous ones. Only after executing `_onChange()` again, the value is updated. But not with the current one, but with the previous one, which I would have expected after the first `_onChange()`. Note that the `console.log(foo, bar);` just before the render logs the expected, current values. So there is a delay of "one `_onChange()` in the state variables `foo` and `bar` in `validate()`.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Calling `setFoo` doesn't change the value of `foo` until the next render.

Comment: We might need a bit more context to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should use `useEffect()` with `foo` and `bar` as dependency. The effect will then run if any of `foo` and `bar` change. Also you can just do `setValid(foo.length !== 0)`. No need for the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part is not right:

```
setFoo(val); // setFoo will not change the `foo` until the next render.
_validate();
```

Can you pass the values directly into the `_validate` function?

```
const _validate = (foo, bar) => {
    if(foo.length !== 0) {
        setValid(true);
    } else {
        setValid(false);
    }
}
```

Then pass the values in with `_validate(foo, bar);`.

Another approach would be to put the validate func in an effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(foo.length !== 0) {
        setValid(true);
    } else {
        setValid(false);
    }
}
}, [foo, bar]);
```